# Why do I receive CSRF Token mismatch error in Android Studio even when GET and POST tokens are the same?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, express, csrf

I am working on an android app (android studio) for my friend's website (node.js/mongoDB) and I am working on user login via the app. Everything works fine on the server side but when attempting to login on android the server receives POST 403 error with CSRF Token Mismatch exception. In android studio I am using HttpUrlConnection and in my main RequestServer class I have created a method for GET which will grab the request as a string and return the CSRF token as a substring:

```
public String getCsrf(String url) {
    try {
        urlObj = new URL(url);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(false);

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

        conn.connect();

            //Receive the response from the server
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        jsonstr = result.toString();

        Log.d("getCsrf JSON", "result: " + jsonstr);

        // getting csrf token
        int position = result.indexOf("<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content");
        // position of token in GET response
        String token = result.substring(position + 33, position + 30 + 41);
        System.out.println("Printing CSRF content from string in getCsrf....... " + token);

        return token;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    conn.disconnect();
    return null;
}
```

In my Login class I am adding this token along with my email/password parameters when doing the POST request:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            email = email_txt.getText().toString();
            pwd = pw_txt.getText().toString();
            RequestServer sR = new RequestServer();
            //calling 'getCsrfFromUrl' method from RequestServer class to retrieve token (Async background method)
            String CSRFToken = sR.getCsrfFromUrl("http://192.168.2.6:3000/login"); // Async background method for getCsrf
            System.out.println("token in Login.java: " + CSRFToken);
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("_csrf", CSRFToken); // the token being added to the parameters HashMap matches with the one I am retrieving from my GET request
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", pwd);
            JSONObject json = sR.postJSON("http://192.168.2.6:3000/login", params);// Async background method for makeHttpRequest.....rest of code not shown as error occurs at this postJSON line
    }
```

Now here is the method in my RequestServer class for my POST request:

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url,
                                  HashMap<String, String> params) {

    sbParams = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        // append params on POST 
        if (i != 0){
            sbParams.append("&");
        }
        sbParams.append(key).append("=").append(params.get(key));

        i++;
    }
        // request method is POST
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true); // set to true so that we can POST data to the url

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); // default is GET

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

            paramsString = sbParams.toString();

            wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream()); // Transmit data by writing to the stream returned by this
            wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
            wr.flush(); // clean up
            wr.close();
            System.out.println("POST Response Status: " + conn.getResponseCode() + " " + conn.getResponseMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    try {
        //Receive the response from the server
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        reader.close();
        jsonstr = result.toString();

        Log.d("POST JSON", "result: " + jsonstr);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    conn.disconnect();

    // try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("POST JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString() + " " + jObj);
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jObj;

}
```

Here is my error console in android studio (notice both of the tokens are identical in the print statements, yet I am still getting a CSRF Token Mismatch error):
[android stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizaR.png)

Error returned from server side:
[node POST 403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5FS8.png)

I looked around for a couple of weeks and nothing has been helpful enough for this specific situation. Just wondering what else am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please Update your Android Studio to v2.1.1
It has a fix. It should work!

Comment: hello thank you for your response, unfortunately after updating to v2.1.1 the issue still persists.

Comment: Oops! then there might be some issues anywhere in the code! not sure sorry!